# SharedPreferences per user?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I need to keep a set of preferences per user and another set of preferences for the whole app. The users are kept in a SQLite database.

I will also be using PreferenceFragment to show the preferences.

If I use `getSharedPreferences()` per user and one for the system, will the preference fragments show the correct preferences?

Or should I use tables in my case and either:

1. forego the use of PreferenceFragment and write my own classes and layouts
2. Fill one preferences file on startup based on user and system preferences stored in SQLite

What is the best **practice** in this case?

Comment: make your username is SharedPreference key :)

Comment: afaik PreferenceFragment always uses the default sharedpreferences, so if you were planning on having separate SharedPreferences instances for user and application preferences it will not work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

You can create Multiple Preference File which have Userid associated with it along with a prefix.
Like :-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.text.TextUtils;

/**
 * Created by vikas on 12/14/15.
 */
public class Pref {
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AppName_%s";
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private String mUserId;
    private static Pref sInstance;

    private Pref(Context pContext, String pUserId) {
        mUserId = pUserId;
        mPreferences = pContext.getSharedPreferences(String.format(PREF_NAME, pUserId), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public String getUserId() {
        return mUserId;
    }

    public static Pref getPreferences(Context context, String userId) {
        if (null != sInstance || !TextUtils.equals(sInstance.getUserId(), userId)) {
            sInstance = new Pref(context, userId);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    //write methods for updating in preference files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` is an `XML` file stored on the phone. If you want to save multiple files for multiple user where there is a user->file connection, naturally, you **CAN** do that.

Simply name the preference file with a unique identifier of a user.

Other solution is a **multitenant** database. In database of that sort, every table has a tenant ID column, which is used to filter one user's data from a single table. Everything else is can be the same as for one user.

If the answer needs to be explained further, feel free to comment, and I will try to answer best I know.